# Array subscript c++ (HEAP)

Tags: c++, arrays, heap, subscript

I need help! I am doing a heap that is a array of structures, my reheap down algorithm seems to be wrong, I have tried everything that I know, and this kind of thing works when there is no structure, just the array. So here is the error:

```
main.cpp: In function 'void reheapDown(hitna**, int, int&)':
main.cpp:88: error: invalid types 'hitna**[std::ios_base& ()(std::ios_base&)]' for array subscript
main.cpp:89: error: invalid conversion from 'std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)' to 'int'
```

and the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct hitna{
    string ime;
    int broj;
};

void unos(hitna *heap[50], int &last);
void reheapUp(hitna *heap[], int &last);
void exchange(hitna *&x, hitna *&y);
void reheapDown(hitna *heap[],int parent,  int &last);
void obrada(hitna *heap[], int &last);

int main(){

hitna *heap[50]={0};
int last = -1;
int odg;
do{
    cout<<"- - - I Z B O R N I K - - -";
    cout<<"\n\n1)Unos pacijenata\n";
    cout<<"2)Obrada pacijenata\n";
    cout<<"3)Ispis pacijenata\n";
    cout<<"4)Izlaz\n";

    cout<<"\nOdabir: ";
    cin>>odg;

    switch(odg){
        case 1:          
           unos(heap, last);
            break;
        case 2: 
            obrada(heap, last);
        break;
        case 3:
            for (int i=0;i<=last;i++){
                cout<<heap[i]->ime<<" "<<heap[i]->broj<<endl;
            }
        case 4:break;
        default:
            break;

    };
}while(odg!=4);

return 0;
}

void exchange(hitna *&x, hitna *&y){
    hitna *t = x;
    x=y;
    y=t;

}

void unos(hitna *heap[50], int &last){
    last++;
    heap[last]=new hitna;
    cout<<"IME: ";cin>>heap[last]->ime;
    cout<<"BROJ: ";cin>>heap[last]->broj;

    reheapUp(heap, last);


}
void reheapUp(hitna *heap[], int &last){
    int parent=(last-1)/2;
    if (heap[parent]->broj < heap[last]->broj){
        exchange(heap[parent], heap[last]);
        reheapUp(heap, parent);}

}  



void reheapDown(hitna *heap[],int parent, int &last){
int left = 2 * parent + 1;

if(left<=last){
    int child = left;
    if(left+1<=last) int right = child+1;

    if ((heap[right]->broj) > (heap[left]->broj)) //THIS IS WRONG
            {child = right;}                        //THIS ALSO

    if (heap[parent]->broj < heap[child]->broj){
        exchange(heap[parent], heap[child]);
        reheapDown(heap, child, last);

    }
}

}

void obrada(hitna *heap[], int &last){
    if(last<0) {return;}
    exchange(heap[0], heap[last]);
    last--;
    reheapDown(heap, 0, last);
}
```

Comment: "i have tried everything i know" - have you debugged?

Comment: Any chance of a minimal complete example?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: @arcticme: What does who mean by what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scope for `right` is incorrect.

```
if(left+1<=last) int right = child+1;
```

The identifier `right` only exists inside this if-block, so you cannot use it outside.  You need to decide what is correct in this case.  If that condition `left+1<=last` is not true, should you still execute the remaining code in the function?  If so, you need to declare `right` outside (at the same scope level as `left`), and give it an appropriate value.

I expect you intended something like this:

```
if(left+1 <= last) {
    int child = left;
    int right = left+1;

    if ((heap[right]->broj) > (heap[left]->broj))
        child = right;

    if (heap[parent]->broj < heap[child]->broj) {
        exchange(heap[parent], heap[child]);
        reheapDown(heap, child, last);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks you, that solved my problem, sometimes i just dont see such little mistakes :D